# Why Alpha clip don't function?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm following ducky 3d tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlizedfuIN4&list=RDCMUCuNhGhbemBkdflZ1FGJ0lUQ&index=6 - But when I turned on alpha clip it didn't work, what I could do? I set up eevee and bloom, motion blur, screen space reflection and ambient occlusion. Please help me

[image]

Comment: Did it work? If it worked please mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting blend mode to **alpha blend**

Screenshot:
[image]

If it does not work then try this:

1. Keep the blend mode to alpha blend
2. Replace translucent BSDF to transparent BSDF

Comment: Did it work? If it worked please mark the question solved.

Comment: yes man thank you very much

Comment: Then please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: sorry, how I do?

Comment: On my answer, under the downvote option, there will be a small tick, just click on it.